# .Net Changing page locations in Visual Studio Solution Exp

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, directory

I have a .Net web project. I want to organize my solution explorer and my pages. Because there are 4 type of users and there are many pages. I want to create folders and keep some of the files in them. I've moved the page files into folders but app does not work. So what should i do?

[image]

Comment: What kind of web project is that? ASP.NET WebForms? MVC? Can you explain what do you expect from us? Maybe show your solution directory?

Comment: You need to change the `Page Title` at the very beginning of your web page accordingly. What used to be `Inherits="Myproject.MyWebPage"` is now `Inherits="Myproject.MyFolder.MyWebPage"` Assuming it is a WebForms.

Comment: @JakubSzumiato Post has been edited. (And it is Web Forms)

Comment: @gadria Actually I've tryed that but my code behinds had many error. Like: server side HTML Element (ListBox) "does not exist in the current context. "

Comment: @FurkanAyık did you check the `MasterPageFile` property of `Page Title` too? Maybe that needs a change too. I have been there and this is what worked for me.

Comment: Also, could you tell us what kind of error do you get? Which URL are you testing? It's pretty hard to say anything when the only thing you say is that the app doesn't work.

Comment: @gadria Yes i've also changed my masterPageFile like "~/NewFolder/Main.Master" after your comment. I think i should change CodeBehind="Page.aspx.cs" too. But i dont know how. I tryed "Folder.Audit.aspx.cs" and "~/Folder/Audit.aspx.cs" but it doesn't work.

Comment: @FurkanAyık `CodeBehind` doesn't expect a path like the others so `YourPage.aspx.cs` should still be fine.

Comment: @JakubSzumiato Basically, my code behind file doesn't find.

Comment: @gadria Oh, ok. But where should i look. My code behind codes have many red line :( Seems the elements on aspx page don't exist in code behind

Comment: @FurkanAyık You can always start from scratch(right click into the new folder and use Add to add your pages and copy paste your code into the new page) if you don't feel like tinkering with all these address issues. Not a good solution though but VS can be buggy sometimes.

Comment: @gadria Sensible. Ok, i'll try that. Thank u for your time and effort

Comment: @FurkanAyık `aspx` files have a `Mypage.aspx.designer.cs` file underneath and its namespace is `namespace Mypage{` but it now should be `namespace Myfolder.Mypage{` that's why your code behind has red lines because it can't verify your `aspx` page via the `designer` file.

Comment: @gadria My designer page had been changed correctly but i know the problem now. My namespace in code behind didn't change. So i changed that namespace like you said, and it works now. Thank you :)

Comment: @FurkanAyık glad that we worked it out :) Can you accept as answer please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the `Page Title` at the very beginning of your web page accordingly. What used to be `Inherits="Myproject.MyWebPage"` is now `Inherits="Myproject.MyFolder.MyWebPage"`

Also, `aspx` files have a `Mypage.aspx.designer.cs` file underneath and its namespace is `namespace Mypage{` but it now should be `namespace Myfolder.Mypage{` that's why your code behind has red lines because it can't verify your aspx page via the designer file.

Comment: I have little problem now :d (sorry i just notice that) My master page loses the css. My css file in Styles folder. Do you know why?

Comment: @FurkanAyık you didn't change the location of `Styles`, right?

Comment: Nope. But i just moved my master page in new folder.

Comment: @FurkanAyık Check the line where you point the css file inside the Master page. Maybe you need to re-define the path with a `..` which means to go to the parent directory. Such as `<link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/yourCSS.css" type="text/css" />`